# How to build an external configuration file in Vue.js based on your environment

Tags: javascript, vue.js

does anyone know if it is possible in the build phase to use an external js file as a configuration file? Maybe through the Vue.config.js file?

Anyone have experience in all this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you clarify? What exactly is this file?

Comment: Hi, yes of course it is a configuration file with information that must be changed at runtime for example APIURL etc etc ... in the main I fetch this json file and use it in my application without having to do the build every time a value changes and I was wondering if it was possible to use 1 for development and one for prod and in the build phase find only the prod json file in the dist, I hope I explained a better ...

Comment: Please, provide it for clarity. This is what .env files are for. If they aren't suitable, you could possibly load data from a file and expose it to environment variables. This could possibly happen in Vue.config.js

Comment: 1year and no answer! this m that Vuejs has very gap as a frontend/spa framework.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not like React which supports that out of the box. And since it's not built-in supported, you have to look into 3rd party solutions.

One of these solutions is: https://github.com/tinou98/vue-12factor

#### Example: Make the title change on env variable

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <title>{{ .TITLE }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{ .TITLE }}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

`Dockerfile`

```
# Build application
FROM node:alpine as build-stage

WORKDIR /app

# Install package as a separate layer for improved docker caching
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

# Build the application
COPY . .
RUN npm run build


# Runnable image
FROM tinou98/vue-12factor

COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /srv/http
CMD ["js/*.js", "index.html"] # List file that contain run-time variable
```

Then build and run the image:

```bash
docker build -t vue-12factor-example .
docker run -it --rm -p8080:80 -e TITLE="Changeable title" vue-12factor-example
```

Now a server is running on port 8080, serving the page with injected environement.